# $\lim p(n) = $? where p is a permutations on natural numbers

Tags: calculus

Let $p:\mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$ be a permutation of the natural numbers (bijection).
What is $\lim p(n) = $ ? $n = {1, 2, 3, ...}$

Please explain your answers, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim{p(n)}$? Is $n$ approaching something?

Comment: I am sorry, I have just edited my question.

Comment: Prove directly that for any integer $N$, there is an integer $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $p_n\geq N$. This shows that $p$ has a limit at infinity, and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} p(n)=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

For every fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the set $p^{-1}\left(\left\{ 1,\cdots,n\right\} \right)=\left\{ r\in\mathbb{N}\mid1\leq p\left(r\right)\leq n\right\} $
is finite (as a consequence of injectivity).

If $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is an upper bound of that set then
$\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\left[m>k\Rightarrow p\left(m\right)>n\right]$
(again as a consequence of injectivity).

So we have: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\exists k\in\mathbb{N}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\left[m>k\Rightarrow p\left(m\right)>n\right]$
or in other notation $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p\left(n\right)=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\lim_{n\to \infty}p(n) = m<\infty$. Derive a contradiction. Conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty}p(n) = \infty$.

Comment: That assumes the existence of the limit (not that it's hard to prove).

Comment: @Oliver True. Perhaps it's more "obvious" to prove that $\liminf_{n\to \infty}p(n)=\infty $ instead.